# Ajuda com Meu Modelo de Postagem Personalizado

Tags: html

**eu criei uma modelo de postagem personalizado e queria melhoralo da seguinte forma**

**ele atualmente esta assim**
[image: atual]

eu queria deixá-lo assim [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

com opção de clicar e alterar entre o "requisitos" e a "instalação" para mostrar o texto dentro de cada 1!
 Esse é o codigo da postagem personalizada

```html
<div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="su-tabs su-tabs-style-default" data-active="1" style="-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background: rgb(238, 238, 238); border-radius: 3px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: black; font-family: &quot;droid sans&quot;; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; list-style: none; margin: 0px 0px 1.5em; orphans: 2; outline: 0px; padding: 3px; text-align: start; text-decoration-color: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px;">
    <div class="su-tabs-nav" style="border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box !important; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <div style="margin: 0px;">
        <span class="su-tabs-current" data-target="blank" data-url="" style="background: rgb(255 , 255 , 255); border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: red; cursor: default; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: 700; line-height: 20px; list-style: none; margin: 0px 3px 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; outline: 0px; padding: 10px 15px; transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;"><strong style="border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">REQUISITOS:</strong></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="su-tabs-panes" style="border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: #333333; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box !important; font-size: 13px; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 15px;">
        <div style="margin: 0px;">
          <br /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; color: black; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: center; text-decoration-color: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px;">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="su-tabs su-tabs-style-default" data-active="1" style="-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background: rgb(238, 238, 238); border-radius: 3px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: black; font-family: &quot;droid sans&quot;; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; list-style: none; margin: 0px 0px 1.5em; orphans: 2; outline: 0px; padding: 3px; text-align: start; text-decoration-color: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px;">
    <div class="su-tabs-nav" style="border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box !important; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <div style="margin: 0px;">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <span class="su-tabs-current" data-target="blank" data-url="" style="background: rgb(255 , 255 , 255); border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: red; cursor: default; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: 700; line-height: 20px; list-style: none; margin: 0px 3px 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; outline: 0px; padding: 10px 15px; transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;"><strong style="border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">INSTALAÇÃO:</strong></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="su-tabs-panes" style="border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: #333333; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box !important; font-size: 13px; list-style: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 15px;">
        <div style="margin: 0px;">
          <br /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <br /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas por que você replicou o elemento `su-tabs` por completo e não apenas definiu um novo elemento em `su-tabs-nav` e em `su-tabs-panes`? Você tem ideia de como esse HTML funciona? Poderia explicar elemento a elemento para nós?

Comment: Pq vc não parte de um componente de Tabs pronto? Tem coisa que não vale a pena fazer do 0 ao meu ver... Procure por "Tab component" no Google que vc vai encontrar uma infinidade de exemplos...

Comment: eu vi em um blog, mas eles só apresentam os comando e um modelo bem vago, eu só modifiquei as fontes , cores e arredondei as borda, e queria colocar a instalação e os requisito junto para poder alterar de uma paro o outro para o post não ficar tão longo, deu mó da trabalho para montar esse e a largura se adapta no meu blog perfeitamente. mas obrigado pela atenção

Comment: eu fiz um diferente , ai só fica a imagem Ex: "Requisitos: Clique  aqui para Expandir Expandir" ai mostra o texto! economizo um bom espaço!